# how to read the img format file from the folder using MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, file-io

I am new to MATLAB. I already read one .img file using `fopen` command. How to read the .img files continuously from the folder without knowing header and pixel information [i.e rows and columns].

Also I need to know how to find average pixel value from the image part only.

Comment: `mean(mean(A))` will give you the mean pixel value of the matrix A

Answer (score -1):

I don't know about your image format, but take a look at imread command. That's what you normally do. If you know the format, i.e., bmp, tiff, etc, it takes care of the rest.